# How to get only integer or float input

Tags: python, string, if-statement, input, integer

I am trying to make a calculator in python. However, I want the user to be able to input an integer or float. But not a string, how can I do that?

This is my current code, however, the if statement does not do the intended job.

```
def calculator():
     x = (input("Please enter a number: "))

     y = (input("Please enter a second number"))

     if x or y != int or float:

          print("Invalid input, please enter a number")
          x = input("Please enter a number: ")
          y = input("Now, please enter a second number: Press enter to leave blank: ")
```

Comment: Have you tried `type(x) is not int or type(x) is not float`?

Comment: `A == B or C` is not the same as `A == B or A == C` - it is `(A == B) or (C is True)`

Comment: @marcelh h  it doesn't work since, in the beginning, python assumes the input is a string.

Comment: Is there way to write x = (int(float("Enter a number: "))) 
to get an either integer or float input

Comment: @nutella1555 you are right, I immediately focused on the if statements, but that was not the issue. You find a suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

you could add int or float before the input...
for example:

```
x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
```

So if you entered a string, it would not accept it and result in a Traceback

Comment: thank you.. but I want the user to be able to input a float. Like either a float or an int but not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You input always be a string, even if someone type a number. To convert the input into a int or a float, use :

```
x = int(input("text"))
y = float(input("text"))
```

Note that you should verify the input if you only want numbers, like

```
def check_user_input(input):
    try:
        # Convert it into integer
        val = int(input)
        print("Input is an integer number. Number = ", val)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            # Convert it into float
            val = float(input)
            print("Input is a float  number. Number = ", val)
        except ValueError:
            print("No.. input is not a number. It's a string")


input1 = input("Enter your Age ")
check_user_input(input1)

input2 = input("Enter any number ")
check_user_input(input2)

input2 = input("Enter the last number ")
check_user_input(input2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```py
while True:
    try:
        x = input('Enter int or float:')

        if x.find('.') == -1:
            x = int(x)
            break
        else:
            x = float(x)
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Something went wrong, try again.')

print(type(x))
```

You have a while loop in which the user input is parsed.
If it contains a `.` the user entered a `float` otherwise an `int`, thus the parsing in the respective statements.
If the format is incorrect, a `ValueError` is raised and excepted, printing that the user should try it again. The info could be updated to be more suggestive. However, if either conversion is successful, the while loop is left and the type is printed. The loop could also be left using KeyboradInterrupt `Ctrl + C`.

Comment: @marcel_h  what does     if x.find(".") == -1:      do?

what does == -1     do?

Comment: @nutella1555 as the user input captured by `input` is a string. With this `if` condition you check if the string contains a `.`, which would indicate a `float` was entered. The `find` itself returns the position of the first occurrence or `-1` if it did not find the character. Not finding, in this case,  indicates an `int`was entered, thus the `int` parsing in the `== -1` part. If it is still not an `int`, a `ValueError` is raised. I will update the answer above if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `isinstance` function.

```
def calculator():
    def checker():
        try:
            x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
            assert (isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float))
            y = int(input("Please enter a second number: "))
            assert (isinstance(y, int) or isinstance(y, float))
        except (AssertionError, ValueError):
            print("Invalid input!")
            checker()
    checker()
    # <Your code here...>
calculator()
```